# COPY command not returning row count

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-9.4

I have two DB instances both running PG 9.4

When i issue the `COPY` command in one it will return with the number of rows affected, however in the second DB which is set up the same it will not.

I see nothing in the config that is different or may affect such. The imports do not error and import successfully on both accounts.

The [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-copy.html) states it should return as long as its not stdout.

This line in the documentation looks pertinent, but i'm not sure it applies to my situation.

> Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy is used.

The command i'm issuing is:

```
COPY [tablename] from '/var/lib/pgsql/datafile.csv'
```

At the moment i'm down to looking at putty session variables, but i'm not sure this is the way to go.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Answer (score 3):

When psql is quiet, it doesn't display these messages.

The quiet mode is activated with `-q` or `\set QUIET on`

Example:

```
test=# copy test to '/tmp/foo';
COPY 8
test=# \set QUIET on
test=# copy test to '/tmp/foo';
test=#
```

Comment: This could be it, how can I view what this setting is ?

Comment: I have tried this on both environments and unfortunately its not making a difference, with set on it still does not show.